# gradle: Let the tooling api model call depend on a task from buildscript

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have a build script where a task adds dependencies to a configuration. Then `compileJava` depends on that task.

```
plugins {
    `java-library`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

val setupDeps = tasks.register("setupDeps") {
    doLast {
        dependencies.add("implementation", "org.clojure:clojure:1.10.3")
    }
}

tasks.named("compileJava") {
    dependsOn(setupDeps)
}
```

From the shell this works. But in intellij the tooling api of gradle is used to build the dependency model. And the tooling api does not know that it has to execute this task first. Is there any way to configure this? I could of course always dynamically add the dependencies during configuration phase but i don't want to do that because to find out what needs to be added is slow.

Comment: If **Gradle** is set for Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Build and run using** option - then IDE executes `classes` and `testClasses` [tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_tasks) on build. So when you will build the project from the IDE - it should work.

Comment: Yes, but there are still a lot of error markers of dependencies intellij can not resolve

Comment: I see, you mean not the Build action, but the **Reload** action in IDE then.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.

The task name to dependOn is `:prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel`

So this solves the problem:

```
tasks.findByPath(":prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel")?.dependsOn(setupDeps)
```